# How many switches are ON

Tags: code-golf, math

A class has N student and the class room has N switches (all turned OFF and numbered 1 to N). Each student has an enrollment number assigned from 1 to N. Each student serially (by number) toggles the switches that has a number which is divisible by his/her enrollment number.

Example: Student 1 will turn all the switches ON. Student 2 will turn all even switches OFF. Student N just toggles the Nth switch.

Write a function that takes N as input as returns number of ON switches.
sample I/O

```
Input: 10
Output:3
```

No upper bound for N is given, but greater the scope, better the code. Shortest and innovative function wins

Comment: I think this is way too easy. Essentially this comes down as: »How short can I make an invocation of a library function«.

Comment: Well yes its easy when the trick is out.. without the perfect square trick, we cant be sure how different people would approach this problem.

Comment: This is a fairly well-known problem, I guess. At least I stumbled over it at least two or three times by now, mostly in programming contest contexts. And if you have two ways of approaching the problem with vastly different lengths, then you can be sure everyone will jump at the shorter one as soon as the first one does it.

Comment: @Joey, Totally agreed..

Comment: why did you accept the longest answer? even if you don't understand the others, this is not fair

Comment: @proudhaskeller If you look at the timestamps, you will notice that the OP seems to have accepted the first answer before any others were posted.

Comment: @Joey my answer no longer uses any (named) library functions ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Python, 19 characters

```python
f=lambda n:n**.5//1
```

Perfect squares are the only numbers with an odd number of divisors.

This used to be a **21-character** answer:

```python
f=lambda n:int(n**.5)
```

but since I originally wrote it in 2011, the floor-division `//` operator was introduced, which can replace the `int` call.

As a consequence, the answer is now returned as a floating-point number. (But `f(10) == 3.0` is still a correct number of lockers!)

Comment: I verified that this does work.  However, I would love to know why this works.

Comment: It works because every divisor of a number matches up with a different divisor, so they always come in pairs, producing an even number of divisors. The *sole* exception is if the number is a perfect square, in which case the square root of the number "pairs" with itself, producing an odd number of divisors.

Comment: There's a lovely post at dailywtf.com about this problem.

Comment: @st0le: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Nerds,-Jocks,-and-Lockers.aspx

Comment: Why is this accepted when *all* other answers are shorter?

Comment: @J B : Yes all other answers are shorter than this, The answer was accepted after 5 votes and no other solution by that time. More importantly, this funda could not hv been better!

Comment: in reply to a suggested edit for removing the `f=`: I choose to keep it there because otherwise you just create a lambda but watch it immediately vanish into the aether, unable to be called. you can choose to believe in your heart that it’s a 17-character solution!

Comment: @PaulFisher untrue; the `_` variable gets automatically set to the last evaluated expression. running the lambda definition will set `_` to be that lambda, therefore callable with `_(n)`.

Comment: While that works in an interactive console, like `ipython`, it is not generally true in the context of a regular Python program.

Answer (score 11):

### dc - 5 chars

```
[v]sf
```

Square root in `dc` is `v`. Using stdin/stdout takes 3 chars (`?vp`)

Answer (score 3):

### J, 9 chars

(Just for a simple example on J)

```
f=:[:<.%:
```

floor (`<.`) of square root (`%:`)

Comment: But the correct answer is the floor, not the ceiling.

Comment: @Peter: right, "<." is floor actually. :/ Thanks.

Comment: Why not `<.@%:`? It also never says it has to be a *named* function, so that brings you down to 5.

Comment: @ɐɔıʇǝɥʇuʎs, this is from a time where this was debated (i.e. if J had to use a named verb when the question asked for a function). I don't know what the consensus is now. Also, since OP accepted a 21-char long answer, there is little point in golfing this.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell - 12

Some text so that my post is long enough.

```hs
f=floor.sqrt
```

Comment: i like this because of the elegant use of the composition operator :)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 3

```
int(√(Ans
```

Or in **Stuck** (invalid, since it's from 2015):

```
i/)
```

Or in [**QWERTY Reverse Polish Notation**](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Qwerty_Reverse_Polish_Notation) (valid, from 2009):

```
@r[
```

Not an interesting answer, but I think they win, since I can't find a language that has either one-character integer square root or implicitly reads from input and performs the calculation in two bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 2 bytes

```apl
⌊√
```

Floor of root of the input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FP16OOWf/THrVNeNTb96ir@VHvmke9Ww6tN37UNvFR39TgIGcgGeLhGfw/TcEMAA), [Verify 50 test cases](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9hcGwtZHlhbG9nLWV4dGVuZGVk///ijIriiJr/ZuKGkOKNjuKKg@KNrOKNtMKvM@KGkeKOlVNSQ@KOlVRISVP/4o2qZsKo4o2zNTA)

Answer (score 1):

### GS2, 2 bytes

```
V-
```

The two instructions are parse number, and integer square root, in order.

The reason this works is that the only switches that are on are perfect squares.  Those are the only numbers with an odd number of divisors.

Comment: +1—I spent about an hour looking for the correct language and couldn't find it. However, this language was written after the challenge, so it's technically not valid.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize this challenge was so old.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
tï
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/5PD6//8NDQA) or [verify the first `N` test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/e/qZ6@k8KhtkoKSvd//ksPr/@v8NzUAAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
t   # Square-root the (implicit) input-integer
 ï  # Cast it to an integer (a.k.a. floors)
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 18 bytes

```java
(int)Math.sqrt(n);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY2xDoMwDETn8hUek6ERQ7ds3ZkYqw4uIBoaHJo4SKji29OkYuvk893p3YQrnqf@lcy8OM8w5V9ZpFE1yE9dLfFhTQedxRCgQUPwqQAONzByPoYYri4Sb6JIkrlz8gNHT6k4sqBUeHsWJHUC2P8QqzM9zBkvWvaGxtsd0I9B/tYA2i3wMCsXWS05ZkviGLzUtZS6Ksw9fQE)

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 133 bytes

```java
boolean[]a=new boolean[n];
int c,i=c=0;
for(;++i<=n;)
for(int j=0;++j<= n;)
a[j-1]=j%i==0?!a[j-1]:a[j-1];
for(boolean b:a)
c=b?++c:c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU8xjsIwEOzziqVAiuUD5SSqmBXS9VSUUYqNCcgmrJHtcEKIt@cckqvYZndmVqMZS3da2eNluPVNZzTojkKAPRmGZwYwsyFSTMtwhB/Xc3zk48kCnkPjXNcSVzUht7/wD7lW2fijvwxqLFR2cj5XUpotshJvNMo2SVLaLcLIUmVX3zXapUEsdosJltOaHGZ7aEoSmcZmJ6UutRogjW9j7xm0SrlfH9nvzhzhmnrlh@gNn6sayJ@DeNcEODxCbK9r18f1Lcmx43xuuikKISbP1/AH)

Comment: I'm not sure if answers are allowed to take input from a pre-existing variable, you may want to check the [default input/outputs allowed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)

Comment: I assumed that "Functions may take input via function arguments" meant that, in java, it would translate into "Method arguments"

Comment: I think what most Java answers do here is use a lambda, like `n->(int)Math.sqrt(n);`. It's only three extra bytes in most cases.

Comment: That would make sense. I haven't messed around with lambda in java but will try to do it in further "golfings" :)

Answer (score 0):

## Moonscript 23

Pretty simple and self-explanatory

```
s=(n)->math.floor(n^.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Math++](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B), 6 bytes

```
_sqrt?
```

(Filler Text Because 30-char minimum)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 23 bytes

Basically square-root and floor.

```
Fn.new{|x|x.sqrt.floor}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkKhgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaipkKvuLCoRC8tJz@/qPZ/cGVxSWquXnlRZkmqRqJecmJOjoahgabmfwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 9 bytes

```perl
$_=0|sqrt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagpriwqOT/f0ODf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)